# Using Large Look up table

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, lookup-tables

**Problem Statement :**

I have two tables - Data (40 cols) and LookUp(2 cols) . I need to use col10 in data table with lookup table to extract the relevant value. 
However I cannot make equi join . I need a  join based on like/contains as values in lookup table contain only partial content of value in Data table not complete value.  Hence some regex based matching is required.

**Data Size :**

1. Data Table : Approx - 2.3 billion entries  (1 TB of data)
2. Look up Table :  Approx 1.4 Million entries (50 MB of data)

**Approach 1 :**

1.Using the Database ( I am using Google Big Query) - A Join based on like take close to 3 hrs , yet it returns no result.  I believe Regex based join leads to Cartesian join.

2. Using Apache Beam/Spark -  I tried to construct a Trie for the lookup table which will then be shared/broadcast to worker nodes. However with this approach , I am getting OOM as I am creating too many Strings. I tried increasing memory to 4GB+ per worker node  but to no avail. 
   I am using Trie to extract the longest matching prefix.

I am open to using other technologies like Apache spark , Redis etc. 
Do suggest me on how can I go about handling this problem.

This processing needs to performed on a day-to-day basis , hence time and resources both needs to be optimized .

Comment: Try some back of the envelope style calculations. On a single CPU core, how many string comparisons do you think it's possible to compute per second? Multiply that number by 2.3 billion, then multiply that result by 1.4 million.

Comment: Thanks for the response. However I am expecting more on alternative  algo or design approach which would tackle the problem more efficiently.

Comment: would be great to see more details on your use-case! any domain specifics? any example of col10 and 2 cols in LookUp table? sometimes small detail can change the game!

Comment: How about using BQ partitions for the main table and then for each partition you can pre-calculate this value and store it back in BQ? You would theoretically then be joining way smaller tables/partitions with your lookup table. Something along those lines? Some more information would help.

Comment: @MatjazMuhic - The data is for single partition . Entire table is in 100+TB .

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - Basically col10 - is complete url (eg: http : // cn456.abcd.tech.com ) and lookup table will have shortened urls like (tech.com , abcd.tech.com) . So my goal is to find longest matching lookup value which in this case would be abcd.tech.com. and then extract value corresponding to it.

Comment: ok. so it looks more optimistic than before :o) and what query you are using now that takes 3+ hours and no result, so we know what to compare with?

Comment: does it mean that you are looking for longest match starting from very right position? or match in the middle is also considered as a match?

Answer (score 1):

> However I cannot make equi join

Below is just to give you an idea to explore for addressing in pure BigQuery your `equi join` related issue

It is based on an assumption I derived from your comments - and covers use-case when y ou are looking for the longest match from very right to the left - matches in the middle are not qualified

The approach is to revers both url (col10) and shortened_url (col2) fields and then SPLIT() them and UNNEST() with preserving positions

```
UNNEST(SPLIT(REVERSE(field), '.')) part WITH OFFSET position
```

With this done, now you can do `equi join` which potentially can address your issue at some extend.
SO, you JOIN by parts and positions then GROUP BY original url and shortened_url while leaving only those groups HAVING count of matches equal of count of parts in shorteded_url and finally you GROUP BY url and leaving only entry with highest number of matching parts

Hope this can help :o)

This is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH data_table AS (
  SELECT 'cn456.abcd.tech.com' url UNION ALL
  SELECT 'cn457.abc.tech.com' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'cn458.ab.com'
), lookup_table AS (
  SELECT 'tech.com' shortened_url, 1 val UNION ALL
  SELECT 'abcd.tech.com', 2
), data_table_parts AS (
  SELECT url, x, y
  FROM data_table, UNNEST(SPLIT(REVERSE(url), '.')) x WITH OFFSET y
), lookup_table_parts AS (
  SELECT shortened_url, a, b, val, 
    ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(REVERSE(shortened_url), '.')) len
  FROM lookup_table, UNNEST(SPLIT(REVERSE(shortened_url), '.')) a WITH OFFSET b
)
SELECT url, 
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(shortened_url, val) ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)].* 
FROM (
  SELECT url, shortened_url, COUNT(1) weight, ANY_VALUE(val) val
  FROM data_table_parts d
  JOIN lookup_table_parts l
  ON x = a AND y = b
  GROUP BY url, shortened_url
  HAVING weight = ANY_VALUE(len)
)
GROUP BY url
```

with result as

```sql
Row url                 shortened_url   val  
1   cn457.abc.tech.com  tech.com        1    
2   cn456.abcd.tech.com abcd.tech.com   2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Though the query returns result for very small sample table, however its taking way too long for bigger sample table and eventually it ended with - (Query exceeded resource limits. )  Big Query plan creates way too many re-partition phases during query execution. I think Big query might not be able to handle this problem. Can Spark/Beam help in this case ?

Comment: This is a very creative solution to the problem, but quite brute force, and the join really explodes the row count, and HAVING only filters after the explosion. When you split the lookup table parts, you could safely filter out where offset = 0 because presumably that will be fragments like "com", "org" etc. Going further, the lookup table parts could be pre-generated, filtering out duplicates like "com", "co", "uk.co". If your lookup had 3 columns, URL, shortened_URL, val, then you could run a window function partitioned by url, ordered by shortened_URL desc. Still a massive search space.

Comment: Can BigQuery's execution planner re-arrange CTEs or is it like other database engines and treats them as black boxes? It might explain all the repartition phases.